# SSRS 2005 - Incorrect RunningValue Sum

Tags: reporting-services, sum

I'm running a report with multiple groups and in the end I try to subtract the total assets by total liabilities and equities. The result is off by a penny. And I have no clue why.

Here's the Total Assets & the Total Liabilities and Equities -

> TOTAL ASSETS                                     **383,357,355.23**
>
> TOTAL LIABILITIES AND EQUITIES        **(383,032,370.18)**

Finally the Grand Total -

Here's the expression being used to calculate it -

```
'=RunningValue(Iif(Fields!Group_1.Value = "ASSETS" or Fields!Group_1.Value = "LIABILITIES AND EQUITIES",Val(Fields!CurMonAvgBal.Value), Val(0)), Sum, nothing)'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reminds me of office space - only off by a few pennies.  Dont worry no one will notice it :).

Answer (score 0):

Out by a penny?

```
Owner's Equity = Assets - Liabilities
```

This means OE + L = A and you are out by $324,985.05

Be that as it may, what you most likely have is a rounding error. Try displaying your number with four decimal places and see if there are numbers after the cents that aren't displaying but are interfering with your calculation.